# ValueError: Shapes (3, 46, 2, 2) and (3, 1000) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to write an algorithm to detect multiple diseases through retinal funtus images. I have 1920 retinal funtus images and a csv file containing 45 classes of these images. First I got my files via google drive and used the code below to convert the images to array

```
list_of_pics= list()
for i in range (1,1921):
  image=Image.open("/content/Training_Set/Training/"+ str(i)+".png")
  
  image=image.resize((224,224))
  
  list_of_pics.append(np.asarray(image))
  new_array=np.array(list_of_pics)
```

The shape of my array is:

```
new_array.shape:(1920, 224, 224, 3)
```

Then I read my csv file

```
y=pd.read_csv("/content/Training_Set/RFMiD_Training_Labels.csv")
y.drop("ID",axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Then I split these files into train and test

```
X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(new_array, y, test_size = 0.2,random_state=10)

X_train.shape: (1536, 224, 224, 3)
y_train.shape:(1536, 46)
```

Then I created my vgg16 model

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input, decode_predictions
model=VGG16()
from keras.optimizers import Adam
opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

I applied One Hot Encoding:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test= to_categorical(y_test)
```

Then I tried to train my model

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=3,epochs=5)
```

I got the following error

```
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-385a457d20dc> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=3,epochs=5)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:756 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:203 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:152 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:256 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1537 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4833 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (3, 46, 2, 2) and (3, 1000) are incompatible
```

I am not experienced in deeplerning yet I would be glad if you can help.

Comment: The VGG16 model outputs 1000 classes by default, which is why you're getting (3, 1000) on one side of the comparison. Likely, your labels are currently shaped as (3, 46, 2, 2) and you're comparing the output of the network to those labels. You can run `output = model.call(input)` to preform a single forward pass of the network and examine the shapes of that output. (see: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/VGG16 for adjusting the number of classes output)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the flatten layer and dense layer by yourself. the vgg just have the FCN layers. the shape `(3, 46, 2, 2)` is coming from FCN. so you need something like this:

```
i = tf.keras.layers.Input((224, 224, 3))
x = tf.cast(i, tf.float16)
x = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x)
core = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
                include_top=False, input_tensor=None, weights='imagenet',
                input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=None,
                classifier_activation='softmax')

x = core(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)
```